# OGR FDW only works with UTF-8 databases, postgis install

Tags: centos7, postgresql, extension, postgis

I try to add postgis extension on postgresql95. I use centos7

I follow this link to install postgis:
http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html#PostGIS

I have done with install

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

But when i execute this

```
CREATE EXTENSION ogr_fdw;
```

I get error like this

```
OGR FDW only works with UTF-8 databases
```

How to fix it?